# PHP Socket I/O Methods

Tags: php, sockets

What is the preferred method for reading/writing to TCP/IP sockets in PHP?  There are many, many ways of doing it, including:

- `fread()` and `fwrite()`
- `fgets()` and `fputs()`
- `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`
- `stream_get_contents()`
- `stream_socket_recvfrom()` and `stream_socket_sendto()`
- probably several others that I've not run across...

I realize that `fgets()` and `fputs()` operate a bit differently (by lines instead of arbitrary chunks of data), but I really don't understand the differences in the others and which method would be best for what purposes.

**Edit:**  Also `socket_recv()` and `socket_send()`.

**Edit #2:**  Also `socket_read()` and `socket_write()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With many of these functions, one can specify offsets and max lengths, providing much overlap (and confusion) between them. Generally, however, they are used as described here:

- [fread](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php), [fwrite](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), [stream_socket_recvfrom](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-recvfrom.php), [stream_socket_sendto](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-sendto.php) read/write *a specific number of bytes at a time.*
- [fgets](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), [fputs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php) read/write *a line at a time*.
- [file_get_contents](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [file_put_contents](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), [stream_get_contents](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) read/write *entire streams of content at a time*.

Comment: I've studied the manual pages for all these functions before posting here.  I guess I'm looking for more of an explanation why there are 5+ sets of methods that can all do roughly the same things.  Even the functions which accept offsets/lengths

Comment: @drrcknlsn because that's what PHP is known for. To quote our own Jeff Atwood PHP "is like an virtual explosion at the keyword  and function factory."  (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/php-sucks-but-it-doesnt-matter.html)  There are ton of methods because people wrote a ton of different ways to do the same thing.